# Integrate multiple Python projects

Tags: python

I have 2 Python projects:

```
Proj1(/var/www/proj1)
    venv
    requirments.txt
    app
      fun.py
      fun2.py
    app2
      pdf.py
      somefun2.py


Proj2(/var/www/proj2)
    venv
    requirments.txt
    another
      anotherfun.py
      anotherfun2.py
    someanother
      someanotherfun.py
      pdfproj2.py
```

Both work individually and both have different set of requirements.

Lets say `pdf.py` from `proj1` has a function `generate` which will generate some PDFs. It will take all other modules(`app/fun2` etc) in same project for it.

Now what I want is this functionality(`pdf.py`->generate) I want to call in `pdfproj2.py` in `proj2`.

How is this possible?

Nb: I am not using any frameworks like flask/django etc

Answer (score 5):

There are at least three approaches.

## 1. external call

Change nothing. Pretty much.

Command line callers are already able to take advantage
of `$ python proj1/app2/pdf.py arg...`, invoking `generate()`.
Arrange for `proj2pdf.py` to fork off a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)
and do exactly that.
Nothing changes in project1,
since its public API already supports this use case.

Notice that you might need to carefully finesse the `PATH` & `PYTHONPATH`
env vars, as part of correctly invoking that pdf.py command.
That's the sort of setup that `conda` and `venv` are good at.

## 2. merge projects

This is the quick-n-dirty approach. I do not recommend it.

Create project3, and incorporate source code from both existing projects.
Take the union of all library dependencies.

Now you can call `generate()` in the same address space,
the same process, as the calling python code.
Downside is: ugliness.
The bigger project's codebase is not as easily maintainable.

## 3. packaging

The "right" way to make `generate()` available to project2,
or to *any* project, is to package it up.
Pretend you're going to publish on [pypi](https://pypi.org/).
Doesn't matter if you actually do,
let's just *prepare* for such a possibility.

Create `setup.py` or similar, maybe use [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/),
and create a wheel (or at least a tar) of project1.
There are many ways to do this, and best practices
continue to evolve, so I won't delve into details here.

Now you can list project1 as a dependency in project2's requirements.txt,
and `import` it just like any other dep. Problem solved!

This is the best approach.
It *does* involve a bit of work, and a gentle learning curve.

Comment: Note that OP already shows a packaging setup for each project, including project-specific virtual environments. In order to use one package from another, both would need to be installed in the same virtual environment.